# Why do we use sigmoid fn when we make Mnist Gan example?

Tags: tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

Hello I'm studying `GAN` by using `Mnist` example.
And  I see example code as like below

```
def nn_G(x):
    HL = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W['HL_G']), b['HL_G'])),
    OL = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(HL, W['OL_G']), b['OL_G']))
    return  OL
```

`nn_G(x)` seems like generator definition, `HL` seems hidden layer and
`OL` seems like the Output layer. I can't understand the meaning that we want to get `0 ~ 1` at the `OL`.

Thank you for reading the beginner's question

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends upon the scale of your image data. That means before passing the input image through the neural network, have you scaled your image. If so then in what range.

If you are scaling your input image in the range [0, 1] and passed it to the discriminator model, then you should apply **sigmoid** function at the output of the generator model.

If you are scaling your input image in the range [-1,1] , then apply **tanh** function at the output of the generator model.

**Edit**

Mnist digit images are grayscale images and thus they are in the range 0-1 and coloured images are in range 0-255.

So from here we can conclude that if you are taking **grayscale images** as input use **sigmoid** function and if you are using **colored images** use **tanh** function.

Comment: According to your reply, Mnist Images are may be in range[0,1]! Thank you for your kindness

Comment: @BELEO Yes, mnist digit images are grayscale images thats why they are in range 0-1. Usually colored images are in range 0-255.

Answer (score 0):

Also grayscale images are in the range [0-255], but with only a grey channel (RGB images have 3 channels, Red, Green, Blue)

The reason why your output is in the range [0-1] is because the image is normalized at the beginning (usually by a simple division by 255)

```
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
```

To obtain the original greyscale range is necessary a multiplication by 255 at the end of the processing, because your output is in the range [0-1]